# Error on initializing AutoMapper v6 in ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, automapper-6

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
         cfg.CreateMap<SomeSourceModel, SomeDestinationModel>();
    });

 config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
 var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

I am repeating these code in the project. Thinking to create a common interface IMapper so that I can invoke whenever it is needed to be used.

The solution I create is

```
    private IMapper Mapper(TSource source, TDestination dest)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<source, dest>();
        });

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        return  config.CreateMapper();
    }
```

It doesn't work. The problem is I can't pass source model and destination model as parameters in this way. How to solve this?

**Update 1:**

As @12seconds mentioned, I start initializing `MapperConfigration` in `Global.asax.cs`

In App_Start folder, I created

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<SourceModel1, DestinationModel1>();
        CreateMap<SourceModel2, DestinationModel2>();
        CreateMap<SourceModel3, DestinationModel3>();
        CreateMap<SourceModel4, DestinationModel4>();
        CreateMap<SourceModel5, DestinationModel5>();

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

}
```

In `Global.asax.cs`

```
    public class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
            });
        }
    }
```

And then I tried to call `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();` in several places. When I start running the App, I got same **error messages**:

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate
>   configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a
>   container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the
>   static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or
>   UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the
>   appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

Where I suppose to call `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();`? Did I miss something?

Comment: Why are you repeating `MapperConfiguration` throughout your application? That just need to be initialized once in your `Startup`, and then you can use just use `Mapper.Map<Type>(model)`

Comment: 1. Where is TSource and TDestination coming from is this inside a generic class isntead of a generic function?  
2. What do you mean it doesn work? What the issue?

Comment: Please see my updates

Comment: You only call `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();` once, on your `global.asax`

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508231/automapper-5-2-how-to-configure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved.  `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` should be executed after Mapper initialized.

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
        });

        Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 5.0.x +

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
        });

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();               
    }
}
```