# mapping my Object1 to Object2 got Unsupported mapping Error

Tags: c#, mapping

Ive been looking for an answer to the code ive made but I cant find any solutions and the reason why its giving me this error.

Im trying out mapping my Object1 to Object2 but I got this error, not sure what i missed on my code.

```
Object1 obj1 = this._mapper.Map<Object1>(new Object2());
```

I have tried this different approach too but I still got error

```
//var obj1  = _mapper.Map<Object1>(request.Object2);
```

Error:

```
type": "https://httpstatuses.com/500",
  "title": "Internal Server Error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nObject -> Object1 ...... -> ......",
```

Comment: [Did you configure the objects to be mapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508231/automapper-5-2-how-to-configure)  Also, your error says, 'Object -> Object1' but your code shows Object1 and Object2, is the code you posted the code that returned the error you posted?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake ive made was declaring one class as `public IEnumerable<Class1> Classname`, then the other was just a simple plain `public Class2 Classname`.

Lesson learned:
When Mapping, the properties of class that needs to be map should be identical.

Sorry and thanks for the help really. Made me realize after some answers were posted.